# Nifi:can't import getFileSystem in customProcessor?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-nifi

I want to use `getFileSytem()` for pulling in any file that is newer than the timestamp that we have but  I can't import it (I mean `getFileSytem()`) I have  this code:

```
final FileSystem hdfs = getFileSystem();
final boolean recursive = context.getProperty(RECURSE_SUBDIRS).asBoolean();

final Set<FileStatus> statuses;
try {
    final Path rootPath = new Path(directory);
    statuses = getStatuses(rootPath, recursive, hdfs,
            createPathFilter(context));
    getLogger().debug("Found a total of {} files in HDFS", new Object[]
            {statuses.size()});
} catch (final IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
    getLogger().error("Failed to perform listing of HDFS due to {}", new
            Object[]{e});
    return;
}
```

and here is  my   pom  file dependencies:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-utils</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-mock</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-hdfs-processors</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.2-incubating</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-properties</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-distributed-cache-client-service-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-standard-nar</artifactId>
            <type>nar</type>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Also I want to know if  is it  possible to make regex which can help me count  amount of files which starts with same string?

Answer (score 0):

You won't want to include nifi-hdfs-processors as a dependency in your custom processor. Instead, you will likely want to set nifi-hadoop-libraries-nar as the parent NAR for your custom processor's NAR. Check the [POM for the nifi-hadoop-nar](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-hadoop-bundle/nifi-hadoop-nar/pom.xml) as an example.

Comment: I have  already  have  parent  NAR  what  should i   make  in this  case?

Comment: What parent NAR are you using? You can only have one parent NAR, so you may need to split up your logic into separate NARs, or try to use the existing processors where possible.

Comment: <parent>
        <groupId>me</groupId>
        <artifactId>sde</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

Comment: What  do  you mean under  splitting  logic into  separate nars?

Comment: You have your own custom NAR as the parent? Does that one have a parent? If not you can add the Hadoop libraries NAR as its parent

Comment: I  have  simply  replaced  my  parent   tag  with   hadoop  parent  tag   but  it  didn'  worked  i mean  getFileSystem  and  Directory  aren't  implemented in my  code

Comment: my  own nar  has  parent  like  this  <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-nar-bundles</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </parent>

Comment: How  do  You  think  is  it    because  i  have  generated  my  own  nar in   a  wrong  way?

Comment: Those aren't NAR dependencies, they are POM dependencies. Take a look at the nifi-hadoop-nar POM for the entry with <type>nar</type>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158022/discussion-between-salome-tkhilaishvili-and-mattyb).